# JPA one-to-many Query

Tags: jpa

I have two classes **Inverter** and **Log**, where Inverter has many Logs **(1:n)**. Each Log as a timestamp attribute.

When I query an Inverter I get all Logs by "Inverter.getLog()", that's fine.

However, I want to create a Query which returns an Inverter, just with selected Logs:

```
select t from Inverter t, Log l WHERE t.id = :id AND l.timestamp >= :date
```

This gives me a whole bunch of results, however I want to get 1 Inverter as result with the Logs.timestamp >= :date

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your query asks for all the inverters and logs satisfying the criteria, without doing any join between them.

And you can't have an Inverter loaded with only a partial list of logs. An entity represents what you really have in the database, and not the result of a specific query.

I would just use `em.find()` to get the inverter by ID, and the following query to get all its logs satisfying the criteria:

```
select log from Inverter inverter 
inner join inverter.logs log 
WHERE inverter.id = :id AND log.timestamp >= :date
```

And I would create an object containing the inverter and its partial list of logs.